# Can primer cover up a smoke smell inside house?

Tags: smell, primer

House was formerly owned by a smoker. Will 1 coat of primer(Kilz in my case) cover and seal in odor inside the house?

Comment: Instead of, or in addition to Kilz, consider an ozone generator. Ozone does a good job of removing smoke odor. You can buy a small generator, or rent a larger one to get the job done faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would scrub the walls with TSP first. Smoker residue can bleed through even Kilz in my experience.